# How to implement drag and drop method in angular

Tags: html, angular, drag-and-drop

I need to implement drag and drop method in angular. Can anyone suggest except **cdkDropList**. Might Data to be drag to another list.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Angular Material Drag and Drop then you can use `ngx-sortablejs`.

Here is the demo: https://sortablejs.github.io/ngx-sortablejs/sortable-array

NPM Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-sortablejs

Comment: Thank you so much will be check this one

Comment: ok. If this works for you the please upvote and mark answer as accepted. It will be helpful for others too.

Comment: Sure, I think so it's working but will check more my requirement is possible to do or not. You to click my question

Comment: Is it available to drop another list?

Comment: In that demo link multiple options are there at top. Multiple list option is also there please check.
https://sortablejs.github.io/ngx-sortablejs/multiple-lists